# Decline and delete Meeting request in Outlook using macro

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to create a one click solution to decline and delete all "I'm AFK from 2pm to 3pm" meeting requests that folks in our team send out (which block everyone's calendars).

Idea is to create a Macro which will decline the currently selected Meeting Request and delete it without any prompts.

```
Sub DeclineAndDelete()

    Dim cAppt As AppointmentItem
    Set cAppt = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
    
    MsgBox cAppt.Subject
    
    Dim oResponse As MeetingItem
    Set oResponse = cAppt.Respond(olMeetingDeclined, False)
    oResponse.Delete ' <---- oResponse is set to Nothing'
    cAppt.Delete

    MsgBox "Ho"
    
    Set cAppt = Nothing
    Set oResponse = Nothing

End Sub
```

When I select the Meeting request in my Inbox and run the macro, it pops up a message box with the subject of my selected Meeting Request (`MsgBox cAppt.Subject`). But then while debugging it shows that `cAppt.Respond` returned `Nothing`.

`MsgBox "Ho"` never pops up.

For the sake of it I tried changing `olMeetingDeclined` to `olMeetingAccepted`, it made no difference.

I did read this [Auto-Decline Meeting Invite Run-Time Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56172051/auto-decline-meeting-invite-run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-var) but according to documentation [`Respond` is supposed to return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.respond#return-value) something which is not `Nothing`.

---

EDIT: It seems like `cAppt.Respond()` returns `Nothing` when organizer of the meeting has requested NO responses.

[image]

In other cases, where the responses were requested/allowed, the macro actually works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, but your code works mostly.

You just need to send the response (and change to "True"!)

```
Dim oResponse As MeetingItem
Set oResponse = cAppt.Respond(olMeetingDeclined, True)
oResponse.Send
```

And, instead of deleting the response, delete the item;

```
Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to change it to `True`. But `cAppt.Respond()` still returns Nothing. `oResponse.Send` bombs because `oResponse` is not set. Also I DON'T want to send a response. Just wanted it gone from my calendar and inbox.

Comment: I hate to say this, but are you sure it's "Nothing"? Or does it just give some weird automation error when you run "oResponse.Delete" ? This is the API call - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.respond

Comment: I did step by step debugging and it was "Nothing" in the watch window. Anyway, just back from my vacation and it works ! I don't know what I changed, nothing AFAIK. But thanks you none the less.

Comment: It seems like `cAppt.Respond()` returns `Nothing` when organizer of the meeting has requested NO responses. Otherwise it works.