# Attempting to respond to an Outlook meeting request in VBA always returns "nothing"

Tags: vba, outlook, appointment

I'm working on a simple Outlook VBA script to accept all selected meeting requests. Many online examples suggest something like the following code should work:

```
Sub AcceptItem()
Dim cAppt As AppointmentItem
Dim oRequest As MeetingItem
Dim x As Integer
For x = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Count To 1 Step -1
If (Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(x).MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request") Then
   Set cAppt = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(x).GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
   Set oRequest = cAppt.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, True)
   oRequest.Send
End If
Next x
End Sub
```

But the script always fails at `oRequest.send` -- when I inspect with the debugger, oRequest is always set to `Nothing` after the `Respond` line is executed, rather than containing a MeetingItem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65672635/decline-and-delete-meeting-request-in-outlook-using-macro "... cAppt.Respond() returns Nothing when organizer of the meeting has requested NO responses."

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the `Respond` method in the code you need to check the [AppointmentItem.ResponseRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.responserequested) property which returns a `boolean` that indicates `true` if the sender would like a response to the meeting request for the appointment.

```
For x = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Count To 1 Step -1
  If (Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(x).MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request") Then
    Set cAppt = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(x).GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
    If cAppt.ResponseRequested = True Then
      Set oRequest = cAppt.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, True)
      oRequest.Send
    End If
  End If
Next x
```

Comment: That does appear to be the problem. But how do I set the category for an accepted appointment if no response is requested? When a response is requested, I was using `oRequest.Categories = "XXX"` but when no response is requested, `oRequest` is `Nothing`, and setting the category on the original appointment item (`cAppt.Categories`) doesn't do anything either.

Comment: @AdamJ.Kessel Create a question post.