# How do I set the calendar item category for an appointment request that does not request a response?

Tags: vba, outlook, appointment

I am using VBA to accept certain calendar invites. When the meeting invite requests a response, I'm able to accept and send the response while setting the category for the copy stored on my calendar with the following script (also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462909/attempting-to-respond-to-an-outlook-meeting-request-in-vba-always-returns-nothi)).

Attempt to set category when no response is requested.

```vb
For x = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Count To 1 Step -1
    If (Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(x).MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request") Then
        Set cAppt = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(x).GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
        Set oRequest = cAppt.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, True)
        If cAppt.ResponseRequested = True Then
            oRequest.Send
            oRequest.Categories = "xxxx"
        Else
            cAppt.Categories = "xxxx"
        End If
    End If
Next x
```

When the invite does not request a response, no MeetingItem is generated and setting the category on the original AppointmentItem has no effect (e.g. `cAppt.Categories = "xxxx"`).

Answer (score 0):

After you set the category, you need to save the appointment:

```
cAppt.Categories = "xxxx"
cAppt.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I set the calendar item category with VBA for an appointment request that does not request a response?

You need to set a category on the appointment item in your calendar, not a meeting request in that case.

The [Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.categories) property returns or sets a string representing the categories assigned to the Outlook item. If you don't see the category assigned to the item you need call the `Save` method as Dmitry suggested.

```
For x = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Count To 1 Step -1
  If (Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(x).MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request") Then
    Set cAppt = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(x).GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
    Set oRequest = cAppt.Respond(olMeetingAccepted, True)
    If cAppt.ResponseRequested = True Then
      oRequest.Categories = "xxxx"
      oRequest.Send
    Else
      cAppt.Categories = "xxxx"
      cAppt.Save
    End If
  End If
Next x
```