# AutoDecline&Delete Emails in Outlook Macro

Tags: vba, outlook, appointment

my code below is able to delete the appointment but not able to decline from the specified email addresses(match in code below) . Could someone please debug and help?

This has gotten me stumped! Please help. It deletes the meeting but does not declines. Please check the comments, I have updated the code

```
                 Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
        
        Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
        Dim objMeeting As Outlook.MeetingItem
        Dim objAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
        Dim arrEntryID() As String
        Dim intCounter As Integer
        
        arrEntryID = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
        
        On Error Resume Next
        
        'Get the Outlook instance
        Set objOL = Outlook.Application
        
        If Not (objOL Is Nothing) Then
            
            'Loop through the EntryID array
            For intCounter = 0 To UBound(arrEntryID)
            
                'Check if the Entry ID is valid
                If arrEntryID(intCounter) <> "" Then
                
                    'Get the meeting request by Entry ID
                    Set objMeeting = objOL.Session.GetItemFromID(arrEntryID(intCounter))
                    
                    If Not (objMeeting Is Nothing) Then
                        
                                'Check if the sender's email address matches the specified email addresses
                    If InStr(1, LCase(objMeeting.SenderEmailAddress), "productclub", vbTextCompare) > 0 _
                    Or InStr(1, LCase(objMeeting.SenderEmailAddress), "ampo.communications", vbTextCompare) > 0 _
 Then
                        
                            Set objAppt = objMeeting.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
                                            'Decline the meeting request
                    Set objMeeting = objAppt.Respond(olMeetingDeclined, True)
                    objMeeting.Body = "Automated Message: Thanks but I will not be able to attend"
                    
                    objMeeting.Send
                        
                    'Delete the appointment and the meeting request
                    objAppt.Delete
                            
                            objAppt.UnRead = False
                            'Delete the appointment and the meeting request
                            objAppt.Delete
                            
                        End If
                    End If
                    
                End If 'end of checking if the Entry ID is valid
                
            Next intCounter
        End If
        
        'Release objects from memory
        Set objOL = Nothing
        Set objMeeting = Nothing
        Set objAppt = Nothing
        
    End Sub
    
        
    ErrorHandler:
        'Handle any errors that occur during the code execution
        Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description
        Resume Next
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code under the debugger attached? What value does the `SenderEmailAddress` property return?

Comment: Fix the biggest error and you can debug. Put `On Error GoTo 0` immediately after `Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`. If you always have this match with ` On Error Resume Next` you are automatically a better programmer than 99.9999% of Outlook VBA programmers.

Comment: how is the code I just updated?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the `NewMailEx` event handler you need to use the `Application` instance available in VBA:

```
'Get the Outlook instance
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Creating a new Outlook `Application` instance doesn't make any sense in the event handler.

Second, the `EntryIDCollection` string contains the `EntryID` string which corresponds to the item arrived. There is no need to split the string any longer, this behavior was changed more than 10 years ago.

Third, you need to use the [Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.meetingitem.body) or `RTFBody` properties if you need to include a custom message to the recipient.

Comment: Have you tried running the code under the debugger attached? What value does the `SenderEmailAddress` property return?

Answer (score 0):

Often `SenderEmailAddress)` will be in Exchange format (...Exchange Administrative Group...) not SMTP format (...@...).

```vb
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objAppt As AppointmentItem
    
    'There is only one Entry ID in EntryIDCollection now.
    Set objItem = Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)
    Debug.Print "NewMailEx: " & objItem.Subject
    
    Debug.Print "TypeName(objItem)...: " & TypeName(objItem)
    Debug.Print "objItem.MessageClass: " & objItem.MessageClass
    
    If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
        
        ' This could be in exchange "EX" format (...Exchange Administrative Group...) not SMTP (...@...)
        Debug.Print objItem.senderEmailAddress
        
        If InStr(1, LCase(objItem.senderEmailAddress), "productclub", vbTextCompare) > 0 _
          Or InStr(1, LCase(objItem.senderEmailAddress), "ampo.communications", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
          
            Set objAppt = objItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
            
            Dim oResponse
            ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65672635/decline-and-delete-meeting-request-in-outlook-using-macro
            ' .Respond() returns Nothing when organizer of the meeting has requested NO responses.
            Set oResponse = objAppt.Respond(olMeetingDeclined, True)
            oResponse.Body = "Automated Message: Thanks but I will not be able to attend"
            
            oResponse.Display
            'oResponse.Send
                 
            objItem.UnRead = False
            'objItem.Delete
        End If
        
    End If
    
    'Release objects from memory
    ' Should not be necessary
    'Set objItem = Nothing
    'Set objAppt = Nothing
    'Set oResponse = Nothing
    
End Sub
```